# Proper name for such 'areas'?

Tags: html, css

What is the proper name for separated areas of content - things which are usually separated via divs. For example, on this site, the sidebar, the main content area, the nav area, the header area.

I have been using 'widget' for areas in the content section of my pages, and I'm unsure whether this is accurately describing what I'm styling. Advice?

Comment: What do your "widgets" contain?

Comment: @alexn my widgets generally contain things like lists of categories, maybe a table with a summary of data (like top right on this site), related articles etc

Comment: A [widget](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUI_widget) is probably a bit too specific to be used in this case, unless your 'things' clasify as widgets. Personally, I would happily just use 'header', 'sidebar', and 'footer' to describe the different areas/sections

Comment: ..and a downvote..strange SO people..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically speaking if you are seperating them by using `div`'s, then these would be "divisions" of your web page layout.

> The `<div>` element defines logical divisions within the document.

http://webdesign.about.com/od/htmltags/p/bltags_div.htm

Therefore I would refer to areas as things like "sidebar division", "header division", "footer division" etc.. This leaves less room for assumption as to which elements you are referring to.